1 часть цикла делает все как нужно, но дальше не собирает данные
Весь код
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd




url = 'https://funpay.com/lots/696/'
headers = {
    'Accept' : '*/*',
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0'

}
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
src = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')


links = soup.find_all(class_='tc-item')
reviews = soup.find_all(class_="seller-promo-desc")
names = soup.find_all(class_="media-user-name")
info = soup.find(class_="row").find_all(class_="text-bold")
filter_reviews = None
href = None
data = []
count = 0
soup_1 = None

for link in links:
    href = link.get('href')
    req1 = requests.get(url=href,headers=headers)
    src1 = req1.text
    soup_1 = BeautifulSoup(src1,"lxml")
    count += 1
    print(f'Найдено {count} объявлений о продаже')
    for i in soup:
        info = soup.find_all(class_="text-bold")
        for all_reviews in reviews:
            filter_reviews = all_reviews.text.strip()
            for all_names in names:
                data.append((all_names, info.pop(5), filter_reviews, href))
                df = pd.DataFrame(data)
                df.to_excel('./teams.xlsx')

Всем привет! Моя проблема заключается в том, что вот эта часть цикла отлично работает
for link in links:
    href = link.get('href')
    req1 = requests.get(url=href,headers=headers)
    src1 = req1.text
    soup_1 = BeautifulSoup(src1,"lxml")

а вот эта часть, не исполняется после работы 1 части цикла
for i in soup:
        info = soup.find_all(class_="text-bold")
        for all_reviews in reviews:
            filter_reviews = all_reviews.text.strip()
            for all_names in names:
                data.append((all_names, info.pop(5), filter_reviews, href))
                df = pd.DataFrame(data)
                df.to_excel('./teams.xlsx')

Задумка заключается в том, чтобы 1 часть цикла собирала 1 ссылку, а после 2 часть цикла заходя на эту ссылку собирала нужные мне данные. Но  1 часть цикла собирает все ссылки на сайте, а после код перестает работать. Помогите пожалуйста!

Непонятно, зачем второй цикл (for i in soup:) вообще нужен. Вы же хотите один раз получить все отзывы для каждой ссылки.
К тому же вы создаете объект soup_1, а позже, чтобы найти отзывы, снова обращаетесь к старому soup, но как я понял по описанию, вам нужно обратиться именно к soup_1.
